# navigating back to the previous page in webview

Tags: android

```
package com.example.acedzubair.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://yo.com/");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
                        myWebView.goBack();
                    } else {
                        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

}
Navigating to previous pages in webview,when doing so the app crashes. Tried using the onBackPressed method but the result is same. While checking on console it shows the error stating java.lang.nullPointerException at myWebPage.cangoback

Comment: Even tried onBackPressed but it did'nt work

Comment: Edit your Post with a question and an an explenation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Aaron the post has been editted with complete description can you please help me out???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use field not local variable. field myWebView is not correctly assigned.

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
```